# Looking to multiply all rows of all columns by a constant

Tags: r

I am trying to find a simple (1 line of code or so) to multiply all rows of all columns of a dataframe by 100 for example.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
head(df)

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
2  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
3  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
4  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0   1
5  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   0
6  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1   1
```

The way I am currently doing it;

```
dfX1 <- as.data.frame(df$X1 * 100)
```

But this way I would have to do this 10 times... and then use the cbind function to bind them all back together again.

```
dfFULL <- cbind(dfX1, dfX2, dfX3...)
```

Anybody know of a cleaner way?

Comment: Just do `df*100`. If it's really all numeric columns, you're probably better off using a matrix.

Comment: Well... that was super simple... why was I trying to overcomplicate it... :s

Comment: @IceCreamToucan what if the first column has row names?

Comment: @Apex If the data frame has rownames, they will be preserved from the original `df`. If some columns are character, that method would not work. You could instead use `library(dplyr)` and run `df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ . * 100)`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)